# JQUERY - Show DIV & Grey Background

Tags: jquery

I need to show a DIV and grey the background - maybe drop the opacity.
The if anything outside of the DIV is clicked the DIV disappears and the page is back to how it was.

Is there an easy way to do this?
Preferably with minimal code and no plugins.

thx

Comment: .........and so far you have tried what? Give us a start point or hire a coder for only 40$/h

Answer (score 0):

You can change the css properties of any object with the [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method of jQuery. So to set the background color you could do something like this, assuming that your div has an id of 'myDiv': `$('#myDiv').css('background-color','grey');`.

To hide the div you can use the [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) function: `$('#myDiv').hide();`.

You'll want to trigger this code when any element around the div is clicked, so add a click event listener to those elements. You can do this with the [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method. So lets say you have another div with the id 'anotherDiv' you could do it like this:

```
`$('#anotherDiv').click(function() {
    $('#myDiv').hide();
 });
```